# How to make QML childs of GridLayout have automatic width and height

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a 3x2 Grid and put 6 elements inside of it. I want these 6 elements to have automatic size, that is, have the width and height of one square of the grid.

```
GridLayout {
    columns: 3
    rows: 2
    width: 1280
    height: 720

    MyCustomCppItem {
        someProperty: "hello"
    }
}
```

but if I don't specify a width and height my item isn't even instantiated. How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to specify a size, you have to set the properties `Layout.fillHeight: true` and `Layout.fillWidth: true` in each item in your layout.

The layout will arrange the items to occupy all the available space.